# ssl warnings on https but ONLY when using a link to the site, going to the url directly works fine

Tags: apache, security, ssl

We have an SSL certificate installed on our site. From all tests, it is installed properly. The browser says the site is secure. The certificate was recently changed.

No problems on the site, however - two people in the office have seen the insecure site warning but ONLY when they follow links (one from an email and the other from a facebook post). They are able to use the site normally otherwise but have both sent screenshots of the warning saying "I clicked a link..." - these links were posted by us and do not use some sort of shortener or anything.

I have gone directly to the urls in question. I get no warning. Everything works properly.

We have htaccess redirects: one from http to https (the links in question are not to http:) and one from /www. to /

I have tried mucking with the url to no avail.

Apache server, php pages.

Comment: Show us the **exact** links that users receiving the error click on.  If it works on in a browser, it might be that the client applications (i.e. email and facebook) do not handle the 30? redirections properly, and you need to put the exact link to avoid redirections for these apps.

Comment: Right...  Indeed I did not think it through, you should remove it.  or replace your domain with example.com.  Is there a way you could publish the link to your emails and facebook that ensures no redirect is triggered?